# Xamarin: Firebase.Firestore.FieldValue does not contain a definition for ArrayUnion

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a Xamarin application in iOS and Android that uses Firebase. I'm trying to add a value to an existing array in firestore. In iOS I had no problems using *FieldValue.FromArrayUnion(obj)*. However in Android I'm having a hard time since this method does not exist. Any ideas of how can I add a value into my array without overwriting its data?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm using Native.

Comment: Ah... yes, ArrayUnion and ArrayRemove are missing from the auto binding (they need to add them manually due to the parameter type, should be reported as a bug). You can call those static methods via some JNI code from C#.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me some additional directions on how to do that?

Comment: I looked at the arr that xamarin bund and Xamarin is way behind on the bindings versions of FireStore... I added an answer...

Comment: How you have done this in iOS? Please check my query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003663/how-to-update-elements-in-an-array-of-firestore-document-using-xamarin-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin has not released a nuget package version that is binding the Firestore version that added `FieldValue.arrayUnion` and `FieldValue.arrayRemove`. Those were added in 17.0.5  and the latest version of 18.0.0, so Microsoft is a number of major/minor versions behind.

> Cloud Firestore version 17.0.5
>
> Added FieldValue.arrayUnion() and FieldValue.arrayRemove() to atomically add and remove elements from an array field in a document.

Thus the `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` static methods are missing in

```
id="Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore" version="60.1142.1"
```

Building that binding project from source would be your fastest option:

- https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents

Comment: Do you have any suggestions or workaround for the missing FieldValue.arrayRemove() method for Firestore version 16?. Version 17 has been released but yet unstable.

Comment: @UchennaNnodim The final `71.1705.0` version was released "19 hours" ago...